# read from binary file 2 bytes each time

Tags: c, binaryfiles

Hello im trying finish my project and im confused about read bytes from binary file. my goal is read 2 bytes each time until EOF. i wanna check first , first byte's first bit 0 or 1 and i wanna print out rest 7 bit like integer. also i wanna print out second byte as integer.So i have this

```
short test[2];
while((fread(&test,sizeof(short),1,ifp)!=0)  //ifp is input file pointer
    {
      fread(&test,sizeof(short),1,ifp);
      printf("test first byte :%d\n",test[0]);
      printf("test seocnd byte : %d\n",test[1];
}
```

i dont know im reading true or not and also i couldnt figure out how im gonna get first byte's first bit and rest 7 bit like integer also how im gonna printout second byte like integer.

thnx..

Comment: You read one short(twice). Why do you print two? Also: you should cast the varargs arguments for printf to int, since %d expects an int argument. (will probably be done by argument-padding/stack aligning, but it is still a sloppy habit)

Comment: You should read about bitwise operators.

Comment: yes you guys right  i double checked. i have trouble about binary files. i have to more study on binary files. thnx

Answer (score 4):

The second fread is not necessary, you should not take the address of an array (no `&test`), also you need to use char type which is 1 byte:

```
unsigned char test[2];
while((fread(test,2,1,ifp) == 1)  //ifp is input file pointer
    {
      int first_bit = test[0] & 0x80;
      printf("test first byte 7 bits :%d\n", test[0] & 0x7f);
      printf("test second byte : %d\n",test[1];
}
```

Comment: ok i understand. you are right. i dont need second fread. yes also i read 2 times same data. how about first bit check ? i wanna check first byte's first bit 0 or 1. so for this problem can i use 
if(test[0]>128)  // if its true first bit has to be 1 right ?

Comment: `int first_bit = test[0] & 0x80;` does that. So you can do `if (test[0] & 0x80)` to test if the first bit is **set**.

Comment: yeah i see thnx i working for 9 hours on it i couldnt see sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody guarantees a `short` is 2 bytes, it is *at least* 2 bytes. And you are reading *one* short and using it and the next. Make like so:

```
unsigned char test[2];
while((fread(&test, 1, 2, ifp) > 0) { //ifp is input file pointer
      printf("test first byte: %u, second byte: %u\n", test[0], test[1]);
}
```

This reads two bytes in one go, checks it read something (return value is number of items read), and prints them.

Comment: why we comparing with >0 in while loop ? i dont understand how im gonna find EOF in binary file.

Comment: Because the file ends... and `fread(3)` doesn't return EOF, it returns 0 if nothing could be read.

Comment: hold on wait a minute ;
while((fread(test,2,1,ifp) == 1)  //ifp is input file pointer  im confused now im gonna compare 0 or 1 ??